# Как правильно заполнить массив?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [myArray, setMyArrayState] = React.useState([
    { name: "John" },
    { name: "Sam" }
  ]);
  const [testArray, setTestArrayState] = React.useState([]);

  
  const fillingArray = (array, newArray) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
    if (newArray.length < 100) {
      fillingArray(newArray, array);
    } else {
      setTestArrayState(newArray)
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fillingArray(myArray, testArray)
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h5>Users: </h5>
      {testArray.map((u) => <p>{u.name}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Пытаюсь при загрузке компонента заполнить массив `testArray` дубликатами массива `myArray` до тех пор пока кол-во элементов не станет ~100, но почему-то рендер не происходит. Почему так? И правильный ли я выбрал способ для заполнения массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так попробуйте:

```js
function App() {
  const [myArray, setMyArrayState] = React.useState([
    { name: "John" }, { name: "Sam" }, { name: "Phil" }
  ]);
  const [testArray, setTestArrayState] = React.useState([]);
  
  const fillingArray = (howMany) => {
    const newArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
      newArray.push(...myArray);
     }
     setTestArrayState(newArray)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fillingArray(10)
  }, []); // Поместите [] сюда. Похоже на: mounted

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h5>Users: </h5>
      {testArray.map((u) => <p>{u.name}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: А если в myArray будет больше элементов?

Comment: Да, мне нужно скопировать массив myArray и заполнить testArray. Каждый раз в myArray разное кол-во элементов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз пытался нечто подобное сделать, не разобрался еще полностью как spread работает и вместо (...myArray); делал ([...myArray]);

Comment: Позвольте мне попытаться объяснить: `var a = [1,2,3]`,  `...a` => `1` и `2` и `3`,  `[...a]` => `[1, 2, 3]  (новый массив)` . `newArray.push(...myArray);`  Поэтому `newArray.push(...myArray);`  => `newArray.push({name: 'john'}, ... ... );`

Comment: документация  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax